# Display HTML content scraped using PHP file_get_contents as plain text within a div

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I read a number of forum posts about displaying html contents as plain text in a page but my situation is little different & hence putting a new question.

I have two Divs in a page

1) Input div, where I will let a user insert a URL (say ebay.com as shown below)

```
<div id="inputs">
<h3>Inputs</h3>
    <form id="inputs" method="POST">
        <label for="urltoget">URL to Get: </label>
        <input type="text" name="urltoget" id="urltoget" size="50" value="www.ebay.com"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="geturl" value="Step1">
    </form>
```

2) Output Div, where I want to use PHP & `file_get_contents` to display the contents of the input URL.
The catch is I want to display the output in plaintext & not full HTML within the output div.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
$base_url = $_POST['urltoget'];
$contents = file_get_contents($base_url);
print_r($contents);
```

I am getting the entire ebay page with HTML contents in the output div.

So far I have tried following:

1) `header('content-type: text/plain');` in the PHP code renders the whole page as plain text as expected. However I want only the contents of second output div as plain text & not the entire page.

2) `print_r(htmlentities($contents));` or `echo htmlspecialchars($contents);`Inserting this in the PHP code does not display any content in the second output div. Neither does it throw any error.

3) `var_dump($contents);` Does not work either, it displays following:

```
string

huge blanks space to scroll down & display

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">var ue_t0=ue_t0||+ne'... (length=187558)
```

My question: how can I get the HTML content (including html tags) as plain text within the second div?
Please help!!

================================================================

The solution from Terrymorse did the trick

```
<?php
$rawHTML = '<html><h1>This is a Title</h1></html>';
$encodedHTML = str_replace('<','&lt;',$rawHTML);
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h3>
            The Encoded HTML
        </h3>
        <div style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 12px">
            <pre><?php echo $encodedHTML; ?></pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks to @markb for the suggestion on var_dump. The output looks lot cleaner

Comment: then `echo htmlspecialchars($contents)`. you're dumping the complete text of another html page into the body of your current page, which means it'll be RENDERED as html within the context of your current page. if you want the html as plain text, you'll have to encode the html metachars, e.g. `<` -> `&lt;`

Comment: Thank you Marc for the reply. Even echo htmlspecialchars($contents); does not display any content in the second div, just like print_r(htmlentities($contents)); nor any error

Comment: then do something like `var_dump($contents)`,make sure you actually received anything. print_r is for debug output, but doesn't do a good job for it. if `f_g_c()` fails, it returns boolean false, which prints as a zero-length string. var_dump will tell you the type/value, not just it string representation. and note that print_r and var_dump are for debugging. if you just want to output something directly, use `echo`.

Comment: @MarcB, tried var_dump. Not successful. Updated in my question

Comment: I would think that it would at least show you an error. Is error output turned on? Try putting this at the top of your php file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` And then try `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` again

Comment: even if f_g_c returned false, or an empty string, var_dump would show that as `bool(false)` or `string(0) ""`. if you get NOTHING at all, then something else is wrong.

Comment: @MarcB, error reporting was turned on & I am getting data in f_g_c with print_r or var_dump. But once I put `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` screen just goes blank without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent evaluation of HTML tags simply by converting all instances of `<` to `&lt;`. Example:

```
<?php
$rawHTML = '<html><h1>This is a Title</h1></html>';
$encodedHTML = str_replace('<','&lt;',$rawHTML);
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h3>
            The Encoded HTML
        </h3>
        <div style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 12px">
            <pre><?php echo $encodedHTML; ?></pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, there's the `<xmp>` tag, but it is obsolete. The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) on `<xmp>` recommends using `<pre>` and `<code>` in its place.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I can't modify the scraped HTML & its tags because in subsequent steps I intend to use those tags to extract further data out of it after analyzing the output. As of now I am stuck in the first step :(

Comment: @SagnikPal Simple. If you want to keep the scraped HTML intact, keep the original as `$rawHTML`, but display `$encodedHTML`.

Comment: You saved the day :)

Comment: @SagnikPal I'm glad I could help, do you want to accept my answer?

Comment: Yes I did accept the answer. However since I am new on this site & do not have 15 reputations yet, I got a message that my vote for your answer will be publicly visible once I obtain 15 reputation. Do let me know if there is any other way to accept your answer. I will do it.